# Read/Set Dymola flag from Modelica class

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have a Modelica function that calls an external C function. At the moment, I am only able to run it with the setting `Advanced.CompileWith64 = 2`

I would like to wrap this function in a way that the flag `Advanced.CompileWith64` is set to the value 2 before calling the external function, and afterwards it is set to its original value.

Conceptually, something like this:

```
function myFunctionWithWrapper
  ...
algorithm
  originalFlagValue := readFlag(CompileWith64)
  setFlag(CompileWith64, requiredFlagValue) "set Advanced.CompileWith64 = 2"
  myExternalFunction(...)
  setFlag(CompileWith64, originalFlagValue)
end myFunctionWithWrapper
```

Is there a way to read and to set a Dymola flag from a Modelica class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functions with the annotation `__Dymola_interactive=true` you can simply access those flags using their regular path.

```
function setFlag

protected 
  Integer old_val;

algorithm 

  old_val :=Advanced.CompileWith64;
  Advanced.CompileWith64 :=2;
  // do something
  Advanced.CompileWith64 :=old_val;

  annotation(__Dymola_interactive=true);
end setFlag;
```

Comment: It works, but only when executing the function directly. If I try to call the function from another model, the model doesn't check but throws the error message: Use of undeclared variable Advanced.CompileWith64 in class setFlag. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think this is not possible. Even if Dymola would allow it, setting such a flag during simulation would not be of any use, as anything needed for the model is compiled before the simulation starts.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely another solution as well.

Setting `Advanced.CompileWith64 :=2;` mean compilation and linking for 64-bit. The likely reason it is needed is that some external library only exists as a 64-bit version.

It is possible to handle that case by changing the external code so that instead of having `myExternalFunction.lib` directly in the LibraryDirectory you have a sub-directory `win64` containing that library. The *absence* of a `win32` sub-directory and *presence* of `win64` will force a 64-bit compilation and linking.

(Similarly for other platforms.)